# Able to create a Microsoft Graph subscription using ngrok but not with Azure url

Tags: c#, api, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

I'm doing this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/azure-functions, everything works fine when i use ngrok but if i replace ngrok value with my azure url app function, i get an error in the createdSubscription variable

```
var subscription = new Subscription
                {
                    ChangeType = "created",
                    NotificationUrl = $"{notificationHost}/api/Notify",
                    Resource = $"/users/{payload.UserId}/mailfolders/inbox/messages",
                    ExpirationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(5),
                    ClientState = Notify.ClientState
                };

                // POST /subscriptions
                var createdSubscription = await graphClient.Subscriptions
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(subscription);
```

saying this *System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*', as i said before if i use ngrok everything works but if i use my azure url, no

Comment: (1) share the detailed error response that you receive along with timestamp, requestid
(2) Test the above outside of code and see still you can repro the issue in POSTMAN/Graph explorer as well

Answer (score 0):

The message  *"Object not set to an instance of Object"*  means you are trying to use an object which has not been initialized. This boils down to one of these:

- Your code  *declared*  an object variable, but it did not  *initialize*  it (create an instance or '*instantiate*' it)
- Something which your code assumed would initialize an object, did not
- Possibly, other code prematurely invalidated an object still in use

Check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/15969833) for detailed information.